# iPad compatibility mode uses (unsupported) small iPhone size

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, compatibility

My iPhone app's Deployment Target is iOS 10 (thus, it's for iPhone 5 and later).  I haven't bothered making my many views fit on the small 3.5" iPhone 4 screen size because it will never be used on that small screen (due to the Deployment target being iOS 10).  However, when my app runs on an 9.7" iPad, compatibility mode defaults to the 3.5" screen size, not 4 inch.  I expected the iPad to respect the implication of my Deployment Target setting.  I believe iPhone apps running on 12.9" iPad are shown using iPhone 5 size -- that's what I want.

I'm using Xcode 9.  My iPad is running iOS 11.4.  I'm not using Auto Layout (it's an old app with numerous views -- it used to run on the older iPhones, but I ripped out that code).

How can I get the iPad to respect my Deployment Target setting and use a 4" screen?

Comment: Either make a Universal app and support iPad fully or make your app work on a 3.5" screen.  You can't change how an iPad runs your app in compatibility mode

Comment: A 12 inch iPad Pro should run your iPhone app at iPhone 6 size (375 x 667), not iPhone 5 size. However, you *do still need to support the 3.5 inch size*, as all iPads below 12 inches run apps in compatibility mode at 320x480. Furthermore, the App Store review team use iPads (currently non-pro) when reviewing your app, and will therefore see it at the smallest size. Sorry, but you're going to have to make your app compatible with the 3.5 inch screen size.